# Why is my SQL Connection Timing out?

Tags: sql, vb.net, connection-timeout

In my standalone Windows application I have a connection string:

```
Private Const _sqlDB As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=localACETest;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFileName=C:\ACE DB\localACETest.mdf"
```

To which I am adding a connect timeout (nevermind that this is an absurdly long timeout):

```
";Connect Timeout=1000"
```

Can anyone explain why I have procedures now timing out that were NOT prior to adding the connect timeout?

Here's how I create the connections:

```
        _conn = New SqlConnection(_sqlDB)
        _conn.Open()

        Dim _dr As SqlDataReader
        Dim _cmd As New SqlCommand("Random Stored Procedure", _conn)
        _cmd.Parameters.Add("@BusGrp", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = bg
        _cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

This doesn't seem to happen when I remove the connect timeout and add a command timeout, however:

```
        _cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000
```

While I understand that a command & connection timeout are two different things, it doesn't make sense to me that adding a *connection* timeout to extend the default would cause this problem.

Comment: You have the incorrect property, it should be `Connection Timeout` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: To avoid problems like that I always advise to use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder which doesn't let you build invalid connection strings.

Comment: I was using this as my reference: https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/

Thanks to both of you for your help.

Comment: whats with all the underscores, abbrevations and explicit classname-chaining? Is this your very first application?

Comment: I joined a team that had this system in place...I also don't know what class name chaining is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the incorrect property for a Connection Timeout:

```
Connect Timeout=1000
```

should be

```
Connection Timeout=1000
```

The correct property is outlined in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) for `Connection Timeout`.
Here's the correct way of using a SQL database (taken from the same MSDN documentation):

As discussed via the comments, you're actually *connecting* to an SQL server, there's a better way here:

```
Sub connectToDb()
    myConn = New SqlConnection("Server=(local);Database=[.database name here.];User Id=[.username here.];Password=[.password here.];")
    Dim returnValue As Object
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = myConn

    Try
        myConn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connected to SQL")
    Catch excep As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occurred: " + excep.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

To query the database for something, you can use:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "USE [.database name.]"
    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    cmd.CommandText = "[.SQL query.]"
    returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar() 'You can check the returnValue to see if the query returned anything.
```

If you have an error that multiple queries cannot be executed at the same time, you must enable `MARS` by appending `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` to your connection string.

Comment: Is storing the connection string in a file more efficient than simply placing it at the top of a class?

Comment: @user Probably not, because you'll have to read in the file first which uses more memory and will increase the time taken to get into the database.

Comment: What if you need to change the connection string? Do you replace the program instead of editing the config file? Micro-optimization worthing the flexibility lost?

Comment: @Steve Good point. I'd probably go with storing the connection string in a file *only* if the program was being distributed, and a hardcoded connection string if only the program was being used by one person.

If the database is being used to store program settings, a `Setting` might be better for this than a complete database.

Comment: Though it is working better, I'm testing with the actual value of 1000 and I'm still getting timeouts from my stored procedures way before the timer would ever reach 1000s: "Error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding"

Ideas?

Comment: @user Are you sure you're not overwriting it somewhere else in your code?

Comment: 100% - Looking right at the code there is nothing that would overwrite it before the _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(). Is there a DB setting that would trump the connection string?

Comment: @user I thought you were only opening a local database file? If you're connecting to a full-on SQL Server then I can supply you the working code for this.

Comment: Indeed I am - SQL Server Express. Is there another workaround? I'm clearly not reaching 16 minutes before the timeout error pops up...

Answer (score 0):

The keyword to use in the connection string is either `ConnectTimeout` (no space) or `Connection Timeout`, as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx). You have a space in `Connect Timeout`, and if you set that and are removing the line `_cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000` it's probably ignoring the connection string value since it's the incorrect keyword and using the default of 15 seconds.

Try changing your connection string to use `Connection Timeout=1000`.